# Is there a way to make a property file accessible from all components without importing it in every file?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have lots of components. Importing a property file in all of them that uses it or importing it in the top component and passing the object read from the file to the rest of them feels too much work. Is there any way to `import * as...` in one place and make it accessible from everywhere in my project?

Comment: try to use react [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Enable automatic imports in your editor